# Office online server didn't send UNLOCK action when I closed the session

Tags: alfresco, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I am trying to integrate Office Online Server with Alfresco. I have deployed Office Online and AD server in my VM. 'View' and 'Edit' action both work well in my system.

But there is some problem when I try to use the collaboration edit. Office server should send an "UNLOCK" action with "X-WOPI-LOCK" headers to my server when I'm closing the browser tab, but I never receive it. The only "UNLOCK" action I can receive is someone else trying to fetch "X-WOPI-LOCK" with an incorrect LockId, as following official explain.

> WOPI defines a GetLock operation. However, Office for the web does not use it in all cases, even if the host indicates support for the operation using the SupportsGetLock property in CheckFileInfo. Instead, Office for the web will sometimes execute lock-related operations on files with missing or known incorrect lock IDs and expects the host to provide the current lock ID in its WOPI response. Typically the Unlock and RefreshLock operations are used for this purpose, but other lock-related operations may be used.

And documentation also says there is an "X-WOPI-Editors" header that will be sent with the "PutFile" action, but I can't receive either.

My environment:

- windows_server_2016_vl_x64
- Office online server march_2017_x64

Comment: 1) Can you share your route configuration? It seems suspicious that the `UNLOCK` wouldn't be sent when you close the browser tab. Sometimes, it takes a while to receive it but it always arrives correctly. 

2) Be aware that the docs (https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/PutFile.html) apply to Office 365 and might not apply to the Office Online Server. The same might be true for the `X-WOPI-Editors` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [this question on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1b783d1c-c686-4b2d-b23f-4977e6bed806/wopi-unlock-call-never-gets-triggered-in-chrome-and-latest-edge-browser?forum=os_office) this is a new behaviour in the Chromium engine as of Oct 2019. There is a call to Office Online Server to announce that the editing session is over but it gets stopped by the browser.

Give it a try in IE to check whether it behaves correctly for you. My experience of this is that going in&out of the online editor a couple times will cause me to be forced into readonly mode by my own online sessions when trying to use "Edit in Word" (desktop). Co-authoring would work OK in the online editor just so long as you don't mind being told there are multiple other people currently editing the document and they're all you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue where Chrome is deprecating Sync XHR on Oct 22 2019, affecting WAC's ability to unlock file and shutdown gracefully. So browsers like Chrome and Edge have this issue for powerpoint. For word and excel files this issue has been fixed.
However, it runs fine in Firefox and IE.
No permanent fix is able for ppt as of now, but you can try several temporary solutions:
go to link chrome://flags/#allow-sync-xhr-in-page-dismissal in Chrome set this property as Enabled. The same applies for Edge browser, simply replace chrome with edge in the above link.
Other temporary solutions are mentioned in this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b783d1c-c686-4b2d-b23f-4977e6bed806/wopi-unlock-call-never-gets-triggered-in-chrome-and-latest-edge-browser?forum=os_office